# Is there a way to determine which version of .Netstandard is targeted by a NuGet package?

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, .net-standard

Recently I tried to import SignalR dlls into a Unity project (support for .NET Standard 2.0).  The NuGet package -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client is currently at version 3.1.2. Here are the dependencies listed:

> .NETStandard,Version=v2.0
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client
>
> (>= 3.1.2) Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.Core (>= 3.1.2)

However, when I move these dlls into the Unity project, I'm greeted with an error:

> Error CS1705  Assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.Core' with
> identity 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.Core, Version=3.1.2.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' uses 'netstandard,
> Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'
> which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'netstandard' with
> identity 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'

That makes sense to me, as I don't expect Unity to support Version 2.1 (the table at the [.NET Standard docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard) states that 2.0 is the latest for Unity. I'm able to downgrade the package to Version 1.1, and everything works as expected (at least this error disappears). I determined which version of SignalR.Client to choose by going through each version, installing/copying until the errors disappeared.

The dependencies for 1.1.0 are identical (exception the Core and Client packages are now listed as `(>=1.1.0)` instead of `(>= 3.1.2)`.

**Question:**  Is there a "better" way than guess-and-check to figure out which version of .NET Standard is required, maybe a spec somewhere that shows which version of .NET Standard needs to be supported for a package to be used?

Comment: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.Core [supports netstandard2.0](https://www.fuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.Core/3.1.2). Curious that it's resolving to the dll that targets netstandard2.1 for you.

Comment: I've been a .NET developer for 10 years, but I've only touched Unity a handful of times. What IDE are you using? Is there a project file or something else you can edit to point it towards the proper DLL? The DLL is inside the NuGet package at /lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.Core.dll

Comment: Unity looks for external dlls in the plugins folder, so I've been manually placing them there (essentially building a regular project that uses signalr and grabbing the dll and all required assemblies and dumping them into unity). I guess at some point VS2019 felt that it could grab the dll that supports the latest standard for the Client.Core dependency, even though Client uses .net standard 2.0. I assume that I can control this by target a diff version of .net core, I will have to check that to see if it resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is an easy way.

[FuGet](https://www.fuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client) lists many details about NuGet packages, including which versions of which frameworks are targeted. For example, Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client 3.1.2 targets netstandard2.0.

A handy shortcut is you're looking at the NuGet page for a package, you can easily get to the Fuget page by just replaying "nuget" in the URL bar with "fuget".

Answer (score 0):

You can check which versions are compatible for a specific package within [nuget.org](https://www.nuget.org/) itself, by checking the *Frameworks* tab:

- Dark blue = `Compatible target framework(s)`
- Light blue = `Additional computed target framework(s)`

[image]